# Getting null values from wcf proxy

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, proxy

I've a C# client which gets data from database from a method in the business layer, using a WCF proxy[basicHttpBinding].
On debugging I find that the data from database comes correctly till the WCF Service layer, but it becomes null at the client level.
What could I be missing over here?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code of your Service?

Comment: Without **any code and config** we can make wild guesses at best.... show us some code!! Explain what you do and maybe someone can spot an error....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that this service use to work and then it stopped working. Before you try anything else, please update your service reference. Usually, values show up as null if there is an incompatibility between the WSDL for the WCF service and the proxy client for that service. This usually happens when the service changes and the proxy client or service reference is not updated.

In case it never worked then we need a code sample and your config file.